# How to change wx.Listbox strings in python

Tags: wxpython

```
self.list_box_1 = wx.ListBox(self, -1, choices = self.generateList("imagelist.txt"), style=wx.LB_SINGLE)

newlist=['6','7','8','9','10']
```

I have a listbox with filenames in it e.g. 1,2,3,4,5 and when a button is clicked I want the listbox to be cleared and the values of newlist overwrite the current values in the listbox

I can change each string in self.list_box_1 using self.list_box_1.SetString(5,1) but how do I overwrite the values in the listbox with the values in newlist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also look for methods for the ListBox in the derivation hierarchy, like [`wx.ItemContainer`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ItemContainer-class.html). 
[`wx.ItemContainer.SetItems`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ItemContainer-class.html#SetItems) might be helpful:

> Clear and set the strings in the control from a list

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Phineas, I used

```
 self.list_box_1.Clear()
 self.list_box_1.InsertItems(newlist,0)
```